# Password encoder, updating password, see if new same as old

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Is there any way to check a plain text password against an encrypted one to see if they're the same?

This using:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
```

BCrypt is the underlying service but the interface is PasswordEncoder.

Say a user has the password 123, the user sends a request to update their password but their new password is also 123. Is there a way to check on the server side if the new and current password are the same?

```
  if (encoder.matches(newPasswordPlainText, oldPasswordEncrypted)) {
    return false;
  }
```

Doesn't seem to work

I'm using BCrypt as encoder.

Comment: pseudo code `if (encrypt(newPassword).equals(oldEncryptedPassword))`

Comment: This doesn't work with BCrypt though?

Comment: @Lithicas How does it not work with BCrypt?

Comment: @Mark It 123 doesn't get hashed and salted the same way twice. Can't compare the encrypted value.

Comment: @Lithicas Then how do people login? You are already verifying the password somehow. Just use that same login logic to determine if the password is the same.

Comment: @Mark that's being handled by Spring Security AuthenticationManager not by me.

Comment: I think you are doing it right, you need to verify if you really passing the right parameter or not, how do you get the oldpassword?

Comment: @slimane I get it from the UserPrincipal, the current user.

Comment: @slimane Getting the value straight from the DB doesn't change anything.

Comment: just making sure you have the right value, I think it will help if you post your UserDetailService

Comment: Well, try with PasswordEncoder, get hash and compare it with the new one?

Comment: @M.Deinum the algorithm should validate the salt/version, so the exception would be thrown if the salt was either incorrect or generated by other incomparable algorithm.

Comment: Not sure how this differs from my, implied, comment. Just pass the new password to the `matches` method with the old encoded password to see if the password matches. If not it is a new password it it matches it is the same. The extracting of the salt and version etc. will be taken care of the `matches` method.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to generate a hash `BCryptPasswordEncoder` needs a raw password (1), a salt (2), and a number of rounds (3). The last two can be determined from the encoded password. It facilitates to create the same hash. Therefore, there is no problem to match a raw password with the encoded one.

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    String encodedPassword = encoder.encode("123");
    System.out.println(encodedPassword + " " + encoder.matches("123", encodedPassword));
}
```

This snippet gives you different hashes, but a firm `true` on `encoder.matches("123", hashOf123)` in all cases:

```
$2a$10$.KLpQ8ESFuWo.lNMN.J3QeUPM2sl5PrGZ1PNortSIUaRxs4T4sN.6 true
$2a$10$Fl7QAFiYKYDcnW28Rg8mMOrrCSIz9eLAkJ2kokXs2LVyV9C1GYJM. true
...
$2a$10$qTXWvu0jEf7kM8DF7HD.fu0qu.kFJID8OmlXLm/6XJUJdA1Dje4vq true
```

Make sure the password stored in the database was encoded by the same algorithm (and the same version) you use for comparing. Otherwise, you might get an exception or an incorrect result.

Comment: Exactly! This method matches() is clearly explained in the Documentation.

Comment: This will always succeed, so not sure what you are testing here. What the OP wants is to test a new password with the already stored password. So `encodedPassword` should be the current one from the user and it should check the current password. Your code will always return `true`.

Comment: @M.Deinum you can assume `encodedPassword` is the password from DB, and `"123"` is a new password

Comment: That isn't what your code is showing, hence my comment.

Answer (score 0):

The only way spring has given that is

```
encoder.matches(newPasswordPlainText, oldPasswordEncrypted)
```

for BcryptPasswordEncoder

And It should be working